# VBA: ADODB: get the values from RECSET.Fields

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

My code is posted below. I can't get the values in ranges "test2" and "test3". I have only the value in range "test". Do I need to modify the code ?

Thank you very much for your suggestions !

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(NO_POLICE As String)

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
RECSET.Open "select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as b_perf_supp_ann, proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from db_dossier sousc, db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.no_police = '" & NO_POLICE & "' and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and sousc.is_protocole = proto.is_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
If Not RECSET.EOF Then
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_cma").Value
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test2").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_supp_ann").Value
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test3").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value
Else
   Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test").Value = "NC"
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test2").Value = "NC"
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test3").Value = "NC"
End If
RECSET.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Any errors?  Maybe your other two fields are nulls?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't have errors. I'm wondering is it right: Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_cma").Value
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test2").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_supp_ann").Value
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("test3").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code (though it would benefit from some refactoring to remove the repeated `Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial")` But is it possible your two missing fields are nulls and not zeros?

Comment: @TimWilliams the missing fields have values 0, but I supposed to have 0 in the ranges.

Comment: @TimWilliams How I can remove the repeated lines ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you ! :)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for you code.I wasn't clear. I mean that my real values are b_perf_cma=1 b_perf_supp_ann=0 b_perf_ctrat_ga=0

Comment: When I running the code I have only the 1 in my range

Comment: I think that I have a problem with RECSET.Fields

Comment: I mean that maybe I can't hold 3 values in one RECSET.Fields ?

Comment: Those are 3 separate fields though, so there should be no problem.  Did you try out my code below?  If that doesn't work then maybe check your named ranges to make sure they are where you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will replace any empty values with zeros

```vba
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(NO_POLICE As String)

    Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    RECSET.Open "select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as " & _
                " b_perf_supp_ann, proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar " & _
                "from db_dossier sousc, db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
                " where sousc.no_police = '" & NO_POLICE & "' and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' " & _
               " and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and " & _
              "sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and sousc.is_protocole = proto.is_protocole ", _
               cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    'use a With block to remove repetition
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial")
    
        If Not RECSET.EOF Then
            .Range("test").Value = CheckValue(RECSET.Fields("b_perf_cma").Value)
            .Range("test2").Value = CheckValue(RECSET.Fields("b_perf_supp_ann").Value)
            .Range("test3").Value = CheckValue(RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value)
        Else
            .Range("test").Value = "NC"
            .Range("test2").Value = "NC"
            .Range("test3").Value = "NC"
        End If
    
    End With
    RECSET.Close

End Sub

Function CheckValue(v)
    'Default to zero if null
    CheckValue = iif(Len(v) = 0, 0, v)
End Function
```